# create a select list with all the values in it rather than 1 select list with 1 value

Tags: php, drupal-6

I am using drupal 6 and I trying to fill a select list with values but at this point I can only get it make 1 select list with 1 value for all the values in the field. I want all the values to be produce in the field in one select list

On top of that I would really like to trim the  to a | character. so ti only has a portion of the field rather than the whole thing.

Here is what I have I just need to modify so it trims for the option value and produces 1 select list that has all the values in it.

```
<?php 
 foreach ($field_reservations as $rfield) {
 echo '<select id="test">';
 echo '<option value="' .$rfield[value]. '">';
 echo $rfield[value]. '</option> <br><br>';
 echo '</select> ';
}
?>
```

I can provide any info that would be helpful thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have just one select list echo the opening select tag before the loop and the closing select tag after the loop. Use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to find the position of the | and then [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get the text to the left and right of the |

```
echo '<select id="test">';
foreach ($field_reservations as $rfield) {
    $pos = strpos($rfield['value'], '|');
    $value = substr($rfield['value'], 0, $pos - 1);
    $display = substr($rfield['value'], $pos + 1);
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$display.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Well yeah I can it be something like here is - " this is what I want to be the value | this is what I want to be displayed " So everything prior to the | would be the value and everything after would the other value or shown text thanks